# What do I need to know before opening a line of credit?

Tags: banking, credit-score, line-of-credit

I'm considering opening a line of credit. The main purpose of this LOC would be to cover myself if I overdraw my checking account (I do this occasionally, and pay pretty steep fees every time). With a LOC, I would only pay interest on the overdrawn amount.

I know that this will impact my credit score as a new credit account. Are there any other things I should think of before opening up this LOC?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to consider why you are repeatedly overdrawing your checking account, and find a solution for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will either appear as a new revolving account or not appear at all until you use it. The main impact will likely be the initial hard-pull when you apply, and it will wear off in several months.

Comment: Hard pull impacts report for 12 months. (Per Credit Karma)

Comment: Would there be a fee to set up a LOC, plus it would be treated more as a business account and would charge for almost everything like getting a statement, etc

Comment: @Dheer are you asking me? How would I know? In my bank its just a "credit limit" on the checking account, there's no additional statements. I have no idea what exactly it is that the OP is talking about.

Comment: @littleadv Just thinking loud, as the OP is in US, typically whethere opening and maintaining a Line of Credit would cost. For example in India, to open a Line of Credit there is a initial cost and yearly costs. If so this should also be a consideration cost / benefit apart from the credit score.